# loading csv files - SyntaxError: invalid syntax (python 3.8)

Tags: python, csv

I was working on a project that requires me to add csv file in two places of the code. I have seen kinda similar problem here at stackoverflow. But their problem was due to old python version 2.5. But my python version is 3.8.

```
import csv

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

def load_az_dataset("C:\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv"):
    # initialize the list of data and labels
    data = []
    labels = []

    # loop over the rows of the A-Z handwritten digit dataset
    for row in open("C:\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv"):
        # parse the label and image from the row
        row = row.split(",")
        label = int(row[0])
        image = np.array([int(x) for x in row[1:]], dtype="uint8")

        # images are represented as single channel (grayscale) images
        # that are 28x28=784 pixels -- we need to take this flattened
        # 784-d list of numbers and repshape them into a 28x28 matrix
        image = image.reshape((28, 28))

        # update the list of data and labels
        data.append(image)
        labels.append(label)

    # convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays
    data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
    labels = np.array(labels, dtype="int")

    # return a 2-tuple of the A-Z data and labels
    return (data, labels)
```

It's showing this syntax error
[image]

Comment: Try `open(r"C:\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv")`

Comment: @DonnyFlaw this isn't what's causing the syntax error that OP linked as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused since you are passing the literal string in the method declaration of `load_az_dataset`.

You need to define the parameter to the function as:

```
def load_az_dataset(fileName):
```

Further, if you want to add that file as the default value for the parameter then use:

```
def load_az_dataset(fileName="C:\\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv"):
```

Also, unrelated to the problem, you need to escape the `\` with another `\`.

Try:

```
open("C:\\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv")
```

Comment: This isn't what's causing the syntax error that OP linked as a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing @blorgon, I have updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused by the fact that the file path is in the parameter list in the function definition. This is the culprit:

```py
def load_az_dataset("C:\A_Z_Handwritten_Data\A_Z_Handwritten_Data.csv"):
```

You have no parameters listed in the function definition. You just have a literal string.

Furthermore, you should also either be using raw strings: `r"..."` or escaping your backslashes, as others have mentioned.

Finally, you should be using the `with open(file_path) as f:` pattern to open your file.

Comment: To clarify, your function definition should read `def load_az_dataset(file_path)`, and then when you CALL the function, that's when you put in the file path string.